# Is this interrupt() necessary?

Tags: java, multithreading

Here's the snippet:

```
public class LogService {

    public void stop() {
        synchronized (this) { isShutdown = true; }
        loggerThread.interrupt();    /* Is it necesarry? */
    }

    public void log(String msg) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (isShutdown)
            throw new IllegalStateException(...);
            ++reservations;
        }
        queue.put(msg);
    }

    private class LoggerThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        synchronized (LogService.this) {
                            if (isShutdown && reservations == 0)
                                break;
                        }
                        String msg = queue.take();
                        synchronized (LogService.this) {
                        --reservations;
                        }
                        writer.println(msg);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) { }    /* Do nothing */
                }
            } finally {
                writer.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As the code above, Even if we put **LoggerThread.interrupt()** in stop() method, the interruption just be caught by thread and do nothing.

So is **LoggerThread.interrupt()** necessary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it it necessary. If the queue is empty, this statement `String msg = queue.take();` will block until an element is put in the queue or it is is interrupted.

If you want to guarantee that the thread does not hang you need to interrupt it.

However there seems to be a glitch: if `reservations` is not 0 when you call the `close` method AND the queue is empty, it seems that your loop will keep going and hang on `queue.take()` at the while loop iteration following the interruption.

Comment: Deleting my answer as yours is more accurate.

Comment: So the `InterruptedException` could be passed to `queue.take()`?

Comment: @user2916610 the exception is not passed to the method - the code in `queue.take()` checks whether the thread is interrupted on a regular basis and throws an InterruptedException if the thread is interrupted.

Comment: I forgot to refer that 'reservation' equals the size of `queue`, so in this case is 'LoggerThread.interrupt()' necessary?

Comment: @user2916610 yes - imagine the queue is empty but isShutdown is still false - the LoggerThread will probably be blocked at `queue.take()`. If you call close, the interruption will force `queue.take()` to exit, the execution will continue in the catch block then back to `if (isShutdown && reservations == 0) break;` which will execute `break` if reservations is 0 and exit the loop. Once again, that is assuming that no other code incremented reservations in the mean time. The construct looks quite fragile to me.